# Create dataLayer custom event for external clicks

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am looking to create a dataLayer push event for any time a click is made on any external link - I plan to use it as a trigger to fire a GTM tag for external link tracking. I envision it will be something like this :

```
<script>
Some code to detect clicks on any external links
dataLayer.push({'event': 'eventNameXYZ'});
</script
```

Comment: That's not a real question, is it? In any case, you are correct. You might also want to push a variable with the clicked url.

Comment: Yes it is - I am looking for guidance on how the code will look like - dont know javascript

Answer (score 0):

An example function:

```
function pushToDataLayer() {
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for(var i=0,cnt=links.length;i<cnt;i++) {       
        var current = links[i];
        current.onclick = function() {
              dataLayer.push({
                'href': current.href, 
                'event': 'outbound' // event to trigger a rule in the tag manager
            });
        }
    }   
}
```

(This will be much easier if you use jQuery or something like it). This will attach an click event to all links. The click will push an event and a variable with the clicked href to the dataLayer.

In the Tag Manager you need to create a new rule that triggers a tag on the custom event "outbound" and a Macro with the type dataLayer that catches the "href" dataLayer Variable. You can use this variable in your tags - for example with a GA virtual ´pageview - and have the tags fire with the rule "fire on event "outbound".

The code might not work on all browsers and is a demonstration of a principle rather than production code (plus it will catch all links, you'd need to test for absolute urls or domains name or css class names that suggest an outbound link). I would recommend using jQuery for finding the links and attaching events.